# Wordpress PHP Image change depending on a language

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a piece of code that would allow me to change images or a whole block of a div depending on the language

```
<?php 
if($_SESSION['lang'] == "fr"){
    echo "images/header-fr-4.jpg";
}else{
    echo "images/header-4-en.jpg";
}
?>
```

Is there any other way of doing this in wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

The Gengo plugin for WordPress supports translated posts and pages, as well as template elements depending on language. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gengo/

For example:

```
<?php if (islanguage('en')) echo "You are reading in English"; elseif (islanguage('ja')) echo "You are reading in Japanese"; else echo "You are seeing all posts..."; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
die("SANATIZE YOUR VARIABLE");
echo "images/header-4-".$lang.".jpg";
```

You could always sanitize the variable in the header so you could use it throughout the entire script.